# Cocoa Posting an NSNotification from a subclass within a subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I am having an issue with receiving an NSNotification that is being sent from an NSButton that has been subclassed to detect double clicks. Which itself is used within a subclass of NSView.

When I post the notification to the default notification center it never arrives in my appDelegate where I am listening for it.

Here is my NSButton subclass:

```
#import "DoubleClickButton.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation DoubleClickButton


- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSInteger clickCount = [theEvent clickCount];
    if (2 == clickCount)
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(handleDoubleClickEvent:)     withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}  

-(void)handleDoubleClickEvent:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"DoubleClick");

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"doubleClickButtonNotification" object:nil];
}

@end
```

Listening in my AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching method:

```
//Notification for Double tap notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(doubleTapAction:)
                                             name:@"doubleClickButtonNotification"
                                           object:self];
```

The notification never arrives and doubleTapAction: is never called.

Please could someone point me in the correct direction as it is melting my brain...

Many Thanks in advance

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: User events (as a mouse down) are always delivered on the main thread. Therefore you do not need the `-performSelectorOnMainThread:…`.

To your Q: Likely you misunderstood the object parameter. Why do you set it to `nil` when posting a notification and set it to `self` for adding the observer? Since `nil` is not $anySelf that does not match. You can set this parameter to `nil` when you *add* the *observer*  to get notifications of all senders. So simply do it the other way round. (Setting object to something useful when posting the notification and to `nil`when adding the observer.)

Comment: Thanks so much. This has been driving me mad. When you explain it makes perfect sense. Thanks again. Marked as correct and up voted.

Comment: You're welcome. That kind of bugs causes nightmares.